# undefined method `authenticate_admin_user!' when access activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I cannot get into admin panel after updating my activeadmin, my admin users are store in a table called admin_users.

```
      NoMethodError in Admin::DashboardController#index

      undefined method `authenticate_admin_user!' for #Admin::DashboardController:0x007fe46c3d99d0
      Rails.root: /Users/jianbo/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/iv

      Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
      activeadmin (0.6.2) lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:40:in authenticate_active_admin_user'
      activesupport (3.2.15) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:474:inblock in run_3994836635519503653__process_action__2211030722258422070__callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.15) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in conditionalcallback_around_863'
```

Answer (score 3):

As part of ActiveAdmin configuration you need to define a method on ApplicationController that requires authentication and determines whether the user is an admin (and hence can access ActiveAdmin pages).  The name of this method can be controlled by this setting in the ActiveAdmin initializers:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

The default name for this method is authenticate_admin_user!

If you already have a method that authenticates a user and confirms that they are an admin, just update the config to use that method.  Otherwise you'll need to create this method on the ApplicationController

Comment: I noticed that code in the active_admin initializes, but I didn't modify any code, why the error suddenly showed up? In my case I don't have any custom admin authentication, so I shouldn't change that config right? then what should I do?

Comment: I don't know what version you upgraded from, but it may be that there was a default method in place in a prior version.  In any case, just define the method and it should work.  Are you using devise?  What's the method you're using to authenticate normal users?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have written -- ***devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config***

So in my case i was having -- ***devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config***
So were having same issues after updating it it resolved.